# Performing updates using alternate key in Dynamics 365 WebAPI

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-webapi

Can anyone help, as I believe someone has already faced the issue I'm having.

I have a custom entity (alssc_anglesector) with an alternate key (alssc_name)

```
“alssc_ANGLESector@odata.bind”: “/alssc_anglesectors(alssc_name=’Air’)”,
“alssc_ANGLESector@odata.bind”: “/alssc_anglesectors(alssc_name=’Water Auth/Company’)”,
```

when I create an account and use the first bind with “Air” it works fine, while when using the second “Auth/Company” I got the response

> “message”: “Bad Request – Error in query syntax.”,
>
> “type”: “Microsoft.OData.ODataException”,
>
> “stacktrace”: ” at
> Microsoft.OData.UriParser.ODataPathParser.ExtractSegmentIdentifierAndParenthesisExpression(String
> segmentText, String& identifier, String& parenthesisExpression)

I have also tried to encode it

```
"alssc_ANGLESector@odata.bind": "/alssc_anglesectors(alssc_name=\u0027Water Auth\u002FCompany\u0027)",
```

but the end result was the same.

I’m not being able to overcome this, Any ideas / suggestions ?

could it be a Bug in D365 API WebApi ?

Answer (score 1):

As per the answer in the comment thread: This request is unsupported because it contains Unicode characters

> **Unicode characters in key value**
>
> If the data within a field that is
> used in an alternate key will contain one of the following characters
> <,>,*,%,&,:,/,\ then update or upsert (PATCH) actions will not work.

The suggestion from the Microsoft Docs is to create another field (such as a code, or a simplified name) that does not contain these characters

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/common-data-service/define-alternate-keys-reference-records#unicode-characters-in-key-value

Answer (score 0):

In this case you have to change ’Water Auth/Company’ with ’Water Auth%2FCompany’ because of '/' special character.

I hope it works.

Ugur

Comment: Hi @UgurBe Thanks for the tip bu I had tried that already and didn't work :(. I have also posted my question here - https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/microsoft-dynamics-crm-forum/394029/performing-updates-using-alternate-key-in-dynamics-365-webapi